# jQuery Autocomplete: Event-select

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to submit a form when an item is selected from the menu. I set class on the search form and I am using the event select for it which is found here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#event-select

Now, when you select an item using the keyboard (UP and Down), it works. But if you select an item using the mouse, it gives you the value which is previously typed.

Check this screenr: http://www.screenr.com/7T0s

This is what I use for submitting:

```
$("#searchform-input").autocomplete({
    select: function (a, b) {
        $(".searchform1").submit()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is because the `select` event's default behavior is executed [*after* your event handler is finished running](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L241) (so that you can cancel it if you so choose).

This means that when you click something, your form is submitted before the widget has a chance to populate the `input` properly.

You should be able to fix this by doing what the widget normally does for you:

```
$("#searchform-input").autocomplete({
    select: function (a, b) {
        $(this).val(b.item.value);
        $(".searchform1").submit()
    }
});
```

Now, what you may be wondering is **yes, but why does it work when I use the keyboard?**

This happens because the `focus` event actually populates the focused item in the `input` (look closely; you'll see the `input` populated as you move up and down the list). When you mouseover an item, the `focus` event is called, populating the `input`. When you select something using the `enter` key, the correct value happens to be in the `input` because of the `focus` event.

Comment: This answer is AWESOME. Very excellent explanation to something which was really killing me today. Thanks a lot for your contribution here Andrew!

Answer (score -2):

Hehe. Quite tricky this one, but incredibly simple to solve. Just delay the function 500 milliseconds, after the select event. It works perfectly. JOB DONE!! :)

```
$("#searchform-input").autocomplete({
select: function (a, b) {
    setTimeout(submit,500);
}});
```

Comment: Don't rely on timing when there's a real solution.